# Merge values of array by duplicate keys

Tags: jquery, json

Trying to merge duplicate keys of `json` array and build respective values in `csv` format.

```
A=[{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:1},{a:1,b:6},{a:2,b:5},{a:2,b:3}]
```

Trying to convert in

```
A=[{a:'1',b:'2,1,6'},{a:2,b:'5,3'}]
```

code Which i tried

```
var existingIDs = [];
        A= $.grep(A, function (v) {
            if ($.inArray(v.a, existingIDs) !== -1) {
                return v.b+= ',';
            }
            else {
                existingIDs.push(v.a);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

the output is returns like

```
A=[{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:'1,'},{a:1,b:'6,'},{a:2,b:5},{a:2,b:'3,'}]
```

Comment: Please care to comment.... down voters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary object with `1`, `2` etc from `a` as keys and keep adding on the `b` values, then iterate over that object creating the new array :

```
var A = [{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:1},{a:1,b:6},{a:2,b:5},{a:2,b:3}];
var temp = {};

for (var i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
    temp[A[i].a] =
        temp[A[i].a] === undefined ?
            A[i].b :
            temp[A[i].a] + ',' + A[i].b;
}

A = [];

for (var key in temp) {
    A.push({a: key, b:temp[key]})
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dT8uH/)